# Slope of a Parametrized Curve

Tags: parametric

Say that we have the parametrized curve $x=e^{3t}, y=te^{-t}$.
What would be the slope of this at the point $(1,0)$ and also on which points on the curve would the curve be horizontal?

What I have done:

For the first question, I used $\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$ and found the slope to be 1/3. Is that right? I don’t know how to do the second part though. Can someone help me?

Comment: for the second part, think about what it means for the curve to be "horizontal"—what would its slope be? Find the points $(x,y)$ where this would happen.

Comment: @chharvey It would be 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. The slope $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of a parametric function $\left(x(t), y(t)\right)$ is $\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$.

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}
= \frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}
= \frac{\frac{d}{dt}te^{-t}}{\frac{d}{dt}e^{3t}}
= \frac{e^{-t}(1-t)}{3e^{3t}}
= \frac{1-t}{3e^{4t}}
$$

To find the slope at $(1,0)$ you would need to find the value of $t$ that satisfies $\left(e^{3t}, te^{-t}\right) = (1,0)$, and then evaluate $\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$ at that $t$.

$$e^{3t} = 1 \text{ and } te^{-t} = 0$$

Clearly there is only one solution, $t=0$.

So then $\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}|_{(0)}$ becomes

$$\frac{1-t}{3e^{4t}}|_{(0)}
= \frac{1-0}{3e^{0}}
= \frac{1}{3}$$

For the second part, the curve is horizontal when $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1-t}{3e^{4t}} = 0$, or when $1-t = 0$.

The curve is horizontal when $t=1$, which is at the point $\left(e^3,e^{-1}\right)$.

Comment: What about the second question

Comment: Okay that's what I got. Thank You

Comment: @Isaac — Happy to help! Thanks for the accept. Just for future reference, it is common practice on the SE network to accept *and* upvote the answer you accepted. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did accept. Thank you. I don't have enough rating to upvote.

Comment: If you can I have a conceptual question on polar curves I need help on. I just asked it. Can you help me if you can?

Comment: I'll take a look! (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338833/a-conceptual-polar-curve-question)