# A Conceptual Polar Curve Question

Tags: polar-coordinates

A polar curve has $r=f(\theta), 0\le \theta \le 2\pi$ has a length of $L$ and is closed by a region that has an area $A$. How can I find the area of a region closed by polar curve say $r=4f(\theta)$ with same interval? How would I also find the length of say a polar curve $r=-3f(\theta)$ with same limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Given $r=f(\theta)$ the area of the sector from the center $(0,0)$ and a arc of curve for $a\le\theta\le b$ is:

$$
A= \dfrac{1}{2}\int_a^b [f(\theta)]^2 d\theta
$$
and the arc leght is:

$$
L=\int_a^b \sqrt{[f(\theta)]^2+\left(\dfrac {df(\theta)}{d\theta}\right)^2} d \theta
$$

So you can find your answers.

For  a proof and some exercise you can see [here](https://cims.nyu.edu/~kiryl/Calculus/Section_9.4--Areas_and_Lengths_in_Polar_Coordinates/Areas_and_Lengths_in_Polar_Coordinates.pdf).

Comment: So $4f(\theta)$ is twice area A? No wait 16 times. Right?

Comment: $[4f(\theta]]^2=16f(\theta)^2$  Right!!

Comment: And the length is 3L?

Comment: Yes. it's right.